# Crawled share not showing up in search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-server, search-results

I have a distributed Sharepoint 2013 Search infrastracture as the image below show:

[image]

I crawled like 20 shares successfully. But I'm experiencing the following problem.

After creating an Enterprise Search Center when I do a search I obtain results for some shares and for some others no. The share on which I'm experiencing problem have thousand of items successfully crawled according the crawl log.

I would like to understand where the problem is but I ran out of idea. Do you have any suggestions on how to debug and troubleshoot such a problem?

Comment: Can you open the items on the file share that you expect to see in the search results?

Comment: Yes sure I can open the document with the account used for the crawling. And as the documents are flagged as successfully crawled there is no problem about permission. I really don't know where to further investigate, do you have any suggestions for and advanced troubleshooting for this kind of problem?

Comment: is the content crawl account have adequate permissions for all 20 shares?

Comment: Yes as I said in the previous comment the permission is ok. The items for the share that is not showing up are marked successfully crawled and I can open them from the crawl log (url view). There is no problem about permission, the problem is when I type for example the name of a document of that share in the Enterprise share center I did not get back any result for some share while for other yes.

Comment: What is different about this share than the others? I know that may sound like a dumb question. But figure out everything about this share that is different than the rest. It may be a problem with a number of different things, and you can't successfully "debug" this error. If you have any ideas come back and let me know. I can drill down further.

Comment: Hi what do you mean by difference? From my point of view if sharepoint says that 115k items were successfully crawled there is no problem about the share. Once items are crawled then the work is on the Sharepoint side that is a search will look into internal index, through query processor, etc... I would like just to know if you guys know a way to debug/troubleshooting items already crawled by the crawler. I don't know any specific power-shell comand etc.

Comment: Can you check with fiddler to see if crawl went fine? http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2012/01/04/troubleshooting-sharepoint-search-crawl/

Comment: The question to ask is "Is your account used for the query (not the crawl) has permissions on that unique Share?"

Comment: please turn this into a comment again. I'm asking what is different from a successfully working share, and this one that didnt work. You mentioned it was the largest. Was it the last share that was crawled? Does it have different query account as @Joseph Saad said? You have a successful answer (other shares), and your problem. Compare the two. -- I have had several SharePoint issues that were bizarre, and no debugging could have found the answers. "I once created a web application that said everything was completed. Powershell showed it existed, but IIS didn't have the resources to reset in ti

Comment: Hi Chris you were right, there was a difference in the permissions (i just used the sam for the other shares and everything worked but I really don't know why there was a problem.....), but the weirdness is that no error about permission in crawl log and items were crawled. I hate the lack of troubleshooting tool that SharePoint provide, it's unbelievable how a an Enterprise tool could have such a bad admin experience.

Answer (score 1):

I also would have expected this to be a permissions problem though as you have said - that isn't the case - or at least it doesn't appear to be on the surface.

Here are a few suggestions for troubleshooting / diagnosing the issue:

1. Use a tool such as the SP 2013 search tool - https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/ - to perform a more 'raw' query against the index - as opposed to just doing so from the Search Center.  If you start getting the expected results back in the tool then I'd look at how the Core Search Results web part is configured in the search center, and other site collection search settings - e.g. query rules
2. Review the ULS and consider temporarily turning up the following items to verbose (via Central Admin >  Monitoring > Configure Diagnostic Logging):
   SharePoint Server Search > Query
   SharePoint Server Search > Query Processor
   SharePoint Server Search > Query Throttling
   SharePoint Server Search > QueryCache

Once you've done this then run your queries and check the ULS with ULS Viewer.

As a side note - you may be interested in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/searchguys/archive/2013/05/24/query-troubleshooting-post-1.aspx).

HTH - keen to know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be permissions. Comparing your successful crawls to the crawl that failed showed infact, different permission levels. I do find it odd that the crawl stated it was successful as well.

Side note. Troubleshooting may not always be traveling down the path of log checking, debugging and so forth. I always follow the path of least resistence, and in this case, it was comparing a successful crawl to an unsuccessful one.

Comment: For me comparing the permission it is not a troubleshooting methodology for a huge product like Sharepoint, this is simply lack of troubleshooting tools and lot of bugs of the product